# Zeros of Eisenstein Series

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I just tried to calculate the zeros of the Eisenstein series of weight 4, which should be only at $\rho=e^{i\pi/3}$ and not at $i$.
I don't know where the mistake in the following is. Who can help?

We have $(i+1)^4=-4$ and thus
\begin{align}
    G_4(i) &= \sum_{\substack{(m,n)\in\mathbb Z^2\\(m,n)\neq(0,0)}} \frac{1}{(m+in)^4}
    = \sum_{\substack{(m,n)\in\mathbb Z^2\\(m,n)\neq(0,0)}} \frac{-4}{((i+1)\cdot(m+in))^4}\\
    &= \sum_{\substack{(m,n)\in\mathbb Z^2\\(m,n)\neq(0,0)}} \frac{-4}{((m-n)+i(m+n))^4}
    = \sum_{\substack{(k,l)\in\mathbb Z^2\\(k,l)\neq(0,0)}}\frac{-4}{(k+il)^4}= -4 \cdot G_4(i)
\end{align}
Thus we get $G_4(i)=0$ and $E_4(i)=0$ (which is wrong, as said above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation
$$
\sum_{\substack{(m,n)\neq(0,0)}} \frac{-4}{((m-n)+i(m+n))^4}
    = \sum_{\substack{(k,l)\in\mathbb Z^2\\(k,l)\neq(0,0)}}\frac{-4}{(k+il)^4}
$$
is wrong.  For example, on the right you have a term with $k=1,l=0$.  But there is no term on the left corresponding to it.  On the left, in $(m-n)+i(m+n)$, the real and imaginary parts have the same parity.